# How to get Product images via PHP SDK

Tags: bigcommerce

I want to get the product images using the Bigcommerce PHP library. How would I do that?

```
$products=Bigcommerce::getProducts();
foreach($products as $product) {
    echo $product->name;
    echo $product->price;
}//here i retrieve price and name of products
```

Comment: Look at this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698921/get-image-url-from-bigcommerce-api-with-php

Answer (score 1):

The following code will get you the product images...

```
$products=Bigcommerce::getProducts();
foreach($products as $product) {
echo $product->name;
echo $product->price;
echo $product->images[0]->image_file
}
```

The line

```
echo $product->images[0]->image_file
```

will give you the first image for the specific product. In order to get more than one image, you would need to iterate through the list. To get the exact url, just append your store_url/product_images at the start of the image_file. So the exact url becomes

```
'https://store_url/product_images/'.$product->images[0]->image_file
```

Remember to replace "store_url" with your store link.

Let me know if you need any other assistance.

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

From the code, it looks like the getProductImages has not been implemented. I added a quick patch. Use this pull request if it has not been merged yet (https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php/pull/61)

The code looks like this -

```
$images = Bigcommerce::getProductsImages(243);
print_r($images)
```