# Get image url from BigCommerce API with PHP

Tags: php, image, url, bigcommerce

Can anybody help me to retrieve Image URL for a BigCommerce Product in PHP? I tried with Bigcommerce::getProductImages($product->id); but it doesn't helps. I hope the API gets updated in latest version. Pls suggest an exact solution. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From the code, it looks like the getProductImages has not been implemented. I added a quick patch. Use this pull request if it has not been merged yet (https://github.com/bigcommerce/bigcommerce-api-php/pull/61)

The code looks like this -

```
$images = Bigcommerce::getProductsImages(243);
print_r($images)
```

Answer (score 0):

when iterating thru products you can grab the product ID and loop through this:

```
$images = BigCommerce_Api::getCollection('/products/'.$productID.'/images');

    foreach($images as $image) {
        $curImage=$image->image_file;
            echo '<img src="'.$storeURL.'/product_images/'.$curImage.'"/>';
        }
```

hope this helps