# BigCommerce - Get product image thumbnail urls

Tags: image, api, bigcommerce

I know it is possible to get the image_file url through the [image API call](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/docs/api/v2/resources/products/images#Response), but would it be possible to retrieve the URLs for image thumbnails?

Thanks!

Comment: This helped me. Maybe you can figure it out from here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17604114/fetch-product-images-with-bigcommerce-api

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: api path path here for image //like https://yourdomain.com/api/v2/products/id/images.json,
    method: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {is_thumbnail:true},
    beforeSend : function(req) 
    {
       req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth);
    },
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)                          
   {
       /*code after sucess here*/
   }
});
```

And BC has only one thumbnail image so it return only one image to you.

I hope this will help you